# How to test React component using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have such react stateless component. I need to check if lowbandwidth icon exist when isSmallVideoView is true

```
export const UnmountableVideoLayout: React.StatelessComponent<VideoLayoutProps> = ({
    isSmallVideoView,
    videoComponent,
    videoOverlayComponent,
}: VideoLayoutProps) => (
    <div className={vStyles.topCenterSeparate}>
        <div className={svStyles.box}>
            {isSmallVideoView && (
                <div className={svStyles.lowBandwidthIcon}>
                    <LowBandwidthConnected />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

How I can test LowBandwidthConnected? My test doesn't work

```
it("should render lowBandwidthIcon if isSmallVideoView is true", () => {
    const props = {
        isSmallVideoView: true,
        videoComponent: dummyVideo,
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<UnmountableVideoLayout {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(svStyles.lowBandwidthIcon).length).toBe(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Enzyme documentation on [selectors](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html) if you want to search by CSS class, you need to concat "." with the class name.

So your find method call should look like this:

```
wrapper.find('.' + svStyles.lowBandwidthIcon)
```